# ChartJS BoxWidth not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

First, my JSFidle: https://jsfiddle.net/ethernetz/u8yc4tvb/

At the top of the chart, there is a pink box. I want that box to go away. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768494/how-to-remove-rectangle-box-next-to-the-legend-text-in-chart-js) have done this by adding

```
legend: {
    labels: {
        boxWidth: 0,
    }
},
```

to their code to make the box go away. As you can see, this didn't affect my box at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should move the legend configuration inside the option object  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8yc4tvb/5/)

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
            labels: ['Completion'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [60, 20],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0)',
            ],

            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        cutoutPercentage: 90,
        events: [],
        legend: {
          labels: {
              boxWidth: 0
          }
      }
    }        
});
```

Comment: please check it again @Ethernetz