# chartjs - Remove only the label not the text

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                // This removes both text and label
                display: false
            },
        }
    }
};
new Chart(document.getElementById('my-chart'), config);
```

I just want to remove the label not the text.

[image: chartjs, the label, and the text]

I tried setting the color of the label to transparent as so:

```
datasets: [{
    label: 'My Chart',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    data: numbers,
}]
```

It removes somehow the label, but the text is not centered.

What options should be set in the config object to remove the label and the text to be maintained and centered?

Comment: This could help [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/)

Comment: You should read this: [How to remove rectangle box next to legend text in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768494/how-to-remove-rectangle-box-next-to-the-legend-text-in-chart-js)

Comment: But it seems like your usecase would benefit more from removing the legend altogether and adding a [title](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html)